# DPKG and PERL ERROR when installing stuff on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, dpkg

I have tried:

--`sudo apt-get install locales`
--`sudo apt install libc-bin`
--`apt install --reinstall dpkg`

These all lead to having perl and dpkg errors.

I also tried to run all these in privillaged mode (`sudo -i`) but they all lead to the same outcomes.

This error appears:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
LANGUAGE = "en_SG:en",
LC_ALL = (unset),
LANG = "en_SG.UTF-8"
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: See if this post helps out: https://libre-software.net/linux-server/ubuntu-setting-locale/

Comment: Please review what is on topic in the [help/on-topic]. Stack Overflow is only for _programming_ questions. You might have better luck on [ubuntu.se], [unix.se], or [su]. (Also, what are you doing using Ubuntu 16.04 in 2023?)